# What is the Azure Offer ID

Tags: text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to do some text to speech using the MS speech api at https://www.projectoxford.ai/doc/speech/REST/Output#HTTPHeaders.

The header requires a **X-Search-PartnerEventID** which it explains is an **Azure Offer ID is a required parameter** but nowhere does it explain how one gets one.

Comment: There is some kind of [sign up page](https://www.projectoxford.ai/doc/general/subscription-key-mgmt).  Did you "sign up"?

Comment: These 2015 docs seem to be incorrect.  This header is not required, and is replaced by an Authorization header.  I'll post the example I got working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs appear to be incorrect.  The X-Search-PartnerEventID header is not required and is replaced by an Authorization header.

For a working example in Rebol, see https://github.com/gchiu/Rebol3/blob/master/scripts/language.reb#L295-L304

```
POST
[
    X-Search-AppId: (settings/appid)
    X-Search-ClientID: (settings/clientid)
    X-Microsoft-OutputFormat: "riff-16khz-16bit-mono-pcm"
    Authorization: (join "Bearer " OxfordAccessToken.o/token)
    User-Agent: "TTSRebol"
    Content-Type: "application/ssml+xml"
]
(data)
```